# Single player game into Multiplayer game(Not online)

Tags: multiplayer, single-player

How difficult is it to do this?(Like, do you need to so skilled that you aswell might have created the game yourself) Do you need to change a lot of the code? For example, if I have a single player chess game, where one plays vs the computer. How dooes one make this avaible to play to players offline? Since I no very little about programming, I was hoping that one basically can remove the part controlling the computer, and replace it with a copy of the code for the first player.

Well, for an example:

http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Tower-Defense/Play/Bloons-Tower-Defense-5.html

To make the question less open, is there likely that making a change like this will require less than 50 hours of work?

Comment: Welcome to GameDev.SE, @GHHardy! I guess your question, even if interesting, will be flagged soon as "Opinion based" and "Too broad". We can not know if it would be too difficult to make a local multiplayer game since we know nothing about your game or the project's logic structure. Please state a concrete case and try to ask again, even an "opinion based" question can fit in StackExchange if it is specific enough.

Comment: Your edit, unfortunately, doesn't make the question any more suitable for this site. See the [help]. A better place to ask this kind of question is probably [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your software architecture looks.

When you have a clear separation between user input, ai input, game mechanics and graphic engine, then you should be able to simply switch out the ai input with a second user input.

But when you have tight coupling between the AI code and the other components of your game, then it might be quite a lot of work to decouple these enough to allow a separate input method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot harder than you think (Judging by your words), plus being able to create a game doesn't mean you are able to handle multiplayer gameplay.

I don't know about specific engines, some might help you with online gameplay, but talking just about code:

- You need a server (or servers) (Even if the game is based on 1v1 gameplay, you need a place to store information and do the matchmaking).
- You need to change a great part of the the core code, now information needs to be sent from and to the players computer.

This is explained "grosso modo", there a lot more into it than it seems, but these are the two basic things you need to add/change.